# jQuery how to reveal closest hidden div with class selector

Tags: jquery, select

I researched jQuery closest(), next(), and nextAll() but none relate to my code since I am not targeting an ancestor/sibling/ nor child. I wasn't able to figure out how to select the closest hidden div after clicking a link that is within a span. It works with this code but it smells terrible. What is the correct way to write this? How can I select the "post_comments" class that is hidden below my Add Comment link?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="skittles">
<span>
    <a href="#" class="comment_count">Add Comment</a>
</span>
<span>3 days ago</span>
</div>

<div class="post_comments hidden">
<input class="comment_input" type="text" placeholder="enter your comment" data-type="post" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $(function(){
        $(".comment_count").click(function(e){
            var $test = $(this).parent().parent().next();
            $test.show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

A link to jfiddle of the working but ugly code
http://jsfiddle.net/N5a2v/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(".comment_count").click(function(e){
      $(this).parents("div.skittles").next("div.post_comments").show();        
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N5a2v/13/

Answer (score 1):

The `:hidden` pseudoselector is likely what you want.

Do you want the first hidden div on the page?

```
$(".comment_count").click(function(e){
    var $test = $("div:hidden:first");
    $test.show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5a2v/14/)

---

Or the first hidden `post_comments` div?

```
$(".comment_count").click(function(e){
    var $test = $("div.post_comments:hidden:first");
    $test.show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5a2v/16/)

Comment: thank you for this solution. My biggest worry with using this though is if I end up having hidden div's before "post_comments". I should have been more clear but I learned a lot from this answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your invisible div:

```
<div class="post_comments" style="display:none">
<input class="comment_input" type="text" placeholder="enter your comment" data-type="post" />
</div>
```

In Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".comment_count").click(function(e){          
        $(".post_comments").show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. The reason why this solution is not good for my app is because there are a lot of other fields with the same ".post_comments" class. I need to only reveal the closest one.

Comment: That is where concept of id comes give it a id and select it from id name...Or if you don't wanna do that select only hidden elements of the same class by :hidden"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".comment_count").click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('.skittles').next().show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/N5a2v/18/